How to plot the legend with combined_plot (ggplot2)
I created this script to display some environmental impacts for my research.
`legend_plot <- ggplot(data_longGW, aes(x = Crop_cycleGW, y = kg_CO2_eq, fill = Category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "grey30") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = custom_colors) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"))
legend <- get_legend(legend_plot)
combined_plot <- plot_grid(
  plot_grid(GW, TA, FE, ME, ET, FRS, ncol = 3),
  legend,
  ncol = 1,
  rel_heights = c(1, 0.1)
)
print(combined_plot)`

When I plot the combined plot part, I get this error and the legend is not displayed in the picture:
In get_plot_component(plot, "guide-box") : Multiple components found; returning the first one. To return all, use return_all = TRUE`
When I plot the code, the graph is displayed without the legend.
Is there a way to fix this?
Thanks for your help :)
I tried to add the suggestions from RStudio but it didn't worked

Hi Guido, can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example so that we may better help? With the information provided, nobody can reproduce the error you received.

The code works as expected if I create some synthetic data. and use that to construct legend, GW, TA, FE, ME, ET and FRS.

The error is most likely related to a change in ggplot2s guide system introduced with 3.5.0 which allows to place legends individually and which as of the moment is not accounted for in cowplot::get_legend. There are already some issues on GH related to this which also propose a fix. See https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/202. A workaround would be to use legend <- get_plot_component(legend_plot, "guide-box-bottom") to pick the guide box for your bottom legend.
